# HTML/CSS/JS: How to make a smooth transitioning slideshow where one div fades out to reveal the next div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to make a slideshow with smooth transitions on a website a person requested me to make.

For example, when I click next, the current slide (a div with text and buttons) with fade out and the next slide will reveal.

Here is the HTML (edited thanks to a headstarter):

```
<div id="ssContainer">
    <div class="slideshow" id="selected">
        <img src="images/slideshow/1.jpg" />
        <div class="ssText">
            <h1>Welcome to White Grass</h1>
            <p>Your complete solution to home building</p>
            <a href="" class="btnLink"><button id="portfolioBtn">See Our Portfolio</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="images/slideshow/2.jpg" />
        <div class="ssText">
            <h1>Custom Home Builder</h1>
            <p>Customer satisfaction is our top priority</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="images/slideshow/3.jpg" />
        <div class="ssText">
            <h1>Professional &amp; Experienced</h1>
            <p>A history of exceptional homes</p>
            <a href="" class="btnLink"><button id="contactBtn">Contact Us Now</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img id="prev" alt="Previous Slide" onclick="prev();" src="images/slideshow/leftarrow.png"></img>
    <img id="next" alt="Next Slide" onclick="next();" src="images/slideshow/rightarrow.png"></img>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: display 0.2s;
}

.slideshow img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}

.ssText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.ssText * {
    text-align: center;
}

.ssText h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%);
    padding: 5px;
}

.ssText p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%);
    padding: 5px;
}

.ssText button {
    position: absolute;
}

#prev, #next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

#next {
    right: 0;
}

#prev:hover, #next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%);
}

#selected {
    display: block !important;
}

#portfolioBtn {
    left: 26%;
    transform: translateX(26%);
}

#contactBtn {
    left: 29%;
    transform: translateX(29%);
}

button {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background-color: #0074c2;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: roboto;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
```

Also, the font is Roboto. I added that in the body section of the CSS.

And here are the images:

- [1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp59N.jpg)
- [2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUPSg.jpg)
- [3.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zb05.jpg)
- [leftarrow.png (Chevron Left Icon by Icons8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIjJv.png)
- [rightarrow.png (Chevron Right Icon by Icons8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH09N.png)

I got a pretty basic concept of the JavaScript now thanks to an answer:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
var slides = document.getElementByClassName("slideshow");

function prev() {
     if(slideindex < 1) {
          slideindex = 3;
     }
     else {
          slideindex--;
     }
     
     showSlides();
}

function next() {
     if(slideIndex > 3) {
          slideIndex = 1;
     }
     else {
          slideIndex++;
     }
     
     showSlides();
}

function showSlides() {
     if(slideIndex == 1) {
          slides[0].id = "selected";
          slides[1].id = "";
          slides[2].id = "";
     }
     else if(slideIndex == 2) {
          slides[0].id = "";
          slides[1].id = "selected";
          slides[2].id = "";
     }
     else if(slideIndex == 3) {
          slides[0].id = "";
          slides[1].id = "";
          slides[2].id = "selected";
     }
}
```

Now, here's the problem:

With the `display` transition, the images don't transition from `block` to `none`.

I even tried messing with the `opacity`. Gives me the animation but not the slideshow feel.

Changed code for `.slideshow` and `#selected` section but reverted:

```
.slideshow {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

#selected {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

How do I fix this? Also, tried messing with `z-index`.

Also, I have to click the previous and next button twice to change from slide 3 to 1 or slide 1 to 3. Weird. Would also want a fix for this.

No jQuery, or any external JS scripts besides my own, please.

Comment: I want to delete my question. I decided to restart my slideshow from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question doesn't comply with Stackoverflow in the way that we expect you to show what you have try and show what you researched. Now you are mostly asking us to write code for you.

Some research and reading will help you get a start on the subject:
[how to create transition css javascript](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1CHBF_frCA883CA883&sxsrf=ALeKk01g0XXK_eg3JrbTELMw8hzgBhyXSg%3A1597245230471&ei=Lgc0X52mHIapytMPt6W0IA&q=how%20to%20create%20transition%20css%20javascript&oq=how%20to%20create%20transition%20css%20javascript&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzoECAAQRzoECCEQCjoHCCMQsAIQJ1C2zgJYzOMCYN3kAmgAcAR4AIABbogBuAmSAQQxMi4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwid9dKU-pXrAhWGlHIEHbcSDQQQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

But hey! I've been there too, so, I'll try to give you an example.

**DON'T USE THIS CODE**
This is only for example purposes and it won't achieve exactly what you are asking for. This code only fades the image background and you are trying to change the whole block of code including the image and text.

The goal behind what follows is only to help you get an idea on how things work.

Let's say that you only want to fade in and fade out your slide. For that, I would use opacity CSS property.

```
.slideshow img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

That said, you will have to add some IDs and your function to your clickable images:

```
<img id="slide1" src="images/slideshow/1.jpg" />
<img id="slide2" src="images/slideshow/2.jpg" />
<img id="slide3" src="images/slideshow/3.jpg" />

<img id="prev" alt="Previous Slide" onclick="fadeTransition('prev')" src="images/slideshow/leftarrow.png"></img>
<img id="next" alt="Next Slide" onclick="fadeTransition('next')" src="images/slideshow/rightarrow.png"></img>
```

And then, there is some javacript to help you start with it

```
var currentSlide = 1;//You need a var that contain the current slide that is show
function fadeTransition(side) {
    if ((side === 'prev' && currentSlide === 1) || (side === 'next' && currentSlide === 3)) {return;}
    if (side === 'prev') {var newSlide = currentSlide - 1;}
    if (side === 'next') {var newSlide = currentSlide + 1;}
    document.getElementById('slide'+currentSlide).style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById('slide'+newSlide).style.opacity = 1;
    currentSlide = newSlide;
    return;
}
```

There us a problem with that , on load, all your image will be at opacity 0. You'll have to change the initial state of the first image. At this point, I'll use a class like

```css
.in {
     opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

And into the Javascript, instead of changing `style.opacity` I would add and remove the `in` class and adding it into the HTML for load purposes:

```html
<img id="slide1" class="in" src="images/slideshow/1.jpg" />
```

[javascript change class](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1CHBF_frCA883CA883&sxsrf=ALeKk006Gszw4AtUBnUMe-nlPmGUoJUUjw%3A1597245277030&ei=XQc0X8W5AYaqytMPq96BoAw&q=javascript%20change%20class&oq=javascript%20change%20class&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywE6BAgAEEM6BQgAELEDOggILhCxAxCDAToCCAA6AgguOgQIIxAnOgcIABCxAxBDUKbTL1ir7C9gpu0vaABwAHgAgAGVAYgB2hGSAQQxNy42mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiF3Oyq-pXrAhUGlXIEHStvAMQQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

So now, most of the previous Javascript code blocks are unusable. Keep it in mind that you have to store what the current displayed block is. Restrict your code so the user can't get to a point where he's going to a previous slide when the current slide is the first one.

I hope this will help you in achieving your goal.

Comment: I edited the code on my question now. I used your JavaScript as an idea for my slideshow. Don't know how to make a smooth slideshow though. Please read my question now; it should be more clear.

Comment: I'll assume that what you ask about slideshow is that you want your div moving from right to left or left to right. In this case, instead of using opacity, you'll have to use either the width or the position of the element.